# How to create a table with data with a formula? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, programmers-notepad

I'm learning Python by myself and I was doing an experiment, where I want to create two columns of data (column A and column B). However, my experiment needs calculated data. My goal is to create a data frame myself (as you do in excel), but I want to incorporate the formulas I need to get the calculated values for my data.

Would it be easier to use the `print()` and the escape characters required (`\n` for line break, `\t` for tab), to display a table on the screen such as the following?:

| Hours (n) | Total number |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 200 |
| 5 | 6400 |
| 10 | 204800 |
| 15 | 6553600 |

For example: the formula I'm using to create this table is Total number=200x2^n

Comment: Hi Lara, welcome to StackOverflow. Questions like `Would it be easier to use x or y` are hard to answer because it is mostly subjective what easy for you may be. Use of `print` and line delimiter and tab delimiter however seem like a good approach if you dont want to use python packages like pandas or tabulate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](/q/9535954/90527)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *"could"* use `\n` and `\t` but that will become awkward very quickly.
A better approach is to use
the `f-string` formatting options to align things as needed.
In this example, your calculation (`200 * 2^n`) is part of the list comprehension that creates the table values for printing, all in one go. The `15 + 1` in the range function is needed to include your stated value of **15**.

```py
table_values = [(n, 200 * 2**n) for n in range(0, 15+1, 5)]

print(f"{'Hours (n)':<15} Total number")
print("-" * 28)
for h, t in table_values:
    print(f"{h :<15} {t:}")


# Alternatively, right-aligned and with 000-separators...
print(f"{'Hours (n)':<15} Total number")
print("-" * 28)
for h, t in table_values:
    print(f"{h :>2} {t:>24,}")
```

The output would then look something like this:

```
Hours (n)       Total number
----------------------------
0               200
5               6400
10              204800
15              6553600
```

Alternative output including the number alignment and formatting:

```
Hours (n)       Total number
----------------------------
 0                      200
 5                    6,400
10                  204,800
15                6,553,600
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()

# Add Hours column, starting trom zero, ending at 15 with step size of 5
df['Hours(n)'] = range(0,16,5)

# Calcualtion total number using hours
df['Total number'] = 200* 2**(df['Hours(n)'])

#show dataframe
print(df)

# show datafram in a better format
display(df)
```

The output will look like this

[image]

If you further face any issues, please write me back. Cheers :)